# How can I adjust keyframes of multiple objects when some are invisible?

Tags: animation, graph-editor

I have set up a scene with many objects at 24fps. Now, I increased it to 60 fps (2.5 times more). To keep everything at the same speed, I increased my frame count by 2.5 times. However, I cannot do the same for my objects as some are invisible in both rendering and the viewport. (Easier for previews) I do not want to have to remove their keyframes one by one and re-add them. How should I get about doing this? Is there something in the graph editor I can use?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that. At the bottom of the graph editor there is a ghost button:

[image: Ghost Button]

Push it in, and now you need to make everything visible in the viewport. Since it is keyframed, this won't do anything. Then, without changing frame enter <kbd>a</kbd>. You can now return to the graph editor and edit everything. I just needed to reset the 3d cursor and resize everything